# How to use ChangeNotifier between Stateful Widgets classes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a tab bar view, each tab has its own Stateless widget that has its own appbar and body.
One of the tabs is for Bluetooth settings where it also contains a method to send the data over Bluetooth, but the variable that stores text/data is defined in other dart file/tab in a stateless class. So is there a way I could rebuild the state of Bluetooth class with something like ChangeNotifier whenever a particular function in the other stateless class(that contains the data) is called?

I can pass the value with Navigator, but I don't want to navigate to the Bluetooth page, just want to access the methods defined in the stateless Bluetooth class that is used to send data.